# Installing VS / SQL server on a single user session

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, installation

I'm currently having troubles with Visual Studio and Microsoft SQL Server components. The problem is that each one of those (VS and SQL Server) comes with a bunch of software that gets installed on my PC. Recently it has been causing me a lot of issues, basically, lowering my PC performances.

So the question is, is there any way to install VS/SQL Server ONLY on a specific user account/session. For example if I had a user account called `Work` and another called `Home`, would I be able to install them only on `Work` without having their services run on `Home`?

I hope I made the question clear enough.

I've already tried googling this and looking for a similar question on SO but found no answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Express LocalDB is a version of SQL Server that only runs when it's accessed and then stops when you're done.

"LocalDB is an execution mode of SQL Server Express targeted to developers. LocalDB installation copies a minimal set of files necessary to start the SQL Server Database Engine. Once LocalDB is installed, developers initiate a connection by using a special connection string. When connecting, the necessary SQL Server infrastructure is automatically created and started, enabling the application to use the database without complex or time consuming configuration tasks. "

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll definetely try it out.
How about Visual studio, any idea?

Comment: Sorry. Not sure about VS. You could try an alternate IDE like Visual Studio Code. https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. I won't set this as answer however, as it's only a workaround solution.